# How to get a cell value in a row of table use javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I want to get all the cell value in a row of a table. but what i wrote here is just to get the first row's cell in my table. I want to get the cell value by the row that selected. Thank you and please help.

```
var updateUser = function(e) {
    var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[1];
    var jqTds = $('input', nRow);

    var id = jqTds[1].value;
    var name = jqTds[2].value;
    var address = jqTds[3].value;
    var username = jqTds[4].value;
    var password = jqTds[5].value;
    var role = jqTds[6].value;
}
```

And i also used jquery and ajax for it.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http:/localhost/api/semuaorang',
  dataType: 'text',
  method: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  success: function(response){
    obj = JSON.parse(response);

    for (var i = 0; i < obj.message.length; i++) {\
       tu = $('<tr/>');
       tu.append("<td><input type='text' name='name' class='foo' readonly value='"+obj.message[i].Id+"'></td>");
       tu.append("<td><input type='text' name='name' value='"+obj.message[i].Nama+"'></td>");
       tu.append("<td><input type='text' name='name' value='"+obj.message[i].Alamat+"'></td>");
       tu.append("<td><input type='text' name='name' value='"+obj.message[i].Username+"'></td>");
       tu.append("<td><input type='text' name='name' value='"+obj.message[i].Password+"'></td>");
       tu.append("<td><input type='text' name='name' readonly value='"+obj.message[i].role+"'></td>");
       tu.append("<td> <a href=''><i class='fa fa-check' onclick='updateUser()'></i></a></td>")
       $('#bodyTableUpdate').append(tu);

    }
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error){
    alert(error);
  },
  complete: function(){
 }
});
```

Comment: not sure I understand what the issue is here, can you perhaps clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have attached the event handler using the `onclick` attribute the `this` keyword in the `updateUser()` function will reference the `window`, not the element which raised the event. To achieve what you require you would be better of using an unobtrusive delegated event handler. In jQuery, you can use `on()` to do this:

```js
// in the $.ajax settings:
success: function(response) {
    // Note JSON.parse is not required here - jQuery does it for you automatically
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.message.length; i++) {
        tu = $("<tr/>");
        tu.append('<td><input type="text" name="id" value="' + obj.message[i].Id + '" readonly="true"></td>');
        tu.append('<td><input type="text" name="name" value="' + obj.message[i].Nama + '"></td>');
        tu.append('<td><input type="text" name="address" value="' + obj.message[i].Alamat + '"></td>');
        tu.append('<td><input type="text" name="username" value="' + obj.message[i].Username + '"></td>');
        tu.append('<td><input type="text" name="password" value="' + obj.message[i].Password + '"></td>');
        tu.append('<td><input type="text" name="role" value="' + obj.message[i].role + '" readonly="true"></td>');
        tu.append('<td><a href="#" class="update-user"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></td>')
        $('#bodyTableUpdate').append(tu);
    }
},

// new click handler:
$('#bodyTableUpdate').on('click', '.update-user', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var id = $row.find('input[name="id"]').val();
    var name = $row.find('input[name="name"]').val();
    var address = $row.find('input[name="address"]').val();
    var username = $row.find('input[name="username"]').val();
    var password = $row.find('input[name="password"]').val();
    var role = $row.find('input[name="role"]').val();

    // use the values as required here...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is an index to reference the clicked row. You already have an index provided by the `for` loop, so just insert that into your `onclick`.

```
tu.append("<td> <a href=''><i class='fa fa-check' onclick='updateUser(" + i + ")'></i></a></td>")
```

And in your `updateUser` function, use the `rowIndex` to get the row:

```
var updateUser = function(rowIndex) {
    var nRow = $('#bodyTableUpdate').find('tr')[rowIndex];
    ...
```

This is the simplest solution to your issue, but [Rory's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37146258/3878338) is a good explanation of how `this` works, what you're doing wrong, and good direction on how to do things *right*.